# Tiling problem about dominos

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways to fully-cover a m -by- n rectangle with mn/2 dominoes is: 
$\prod_{j=1}^m \prod_{k=1}^n \left ( 4\cos^2 \frac{\pi j}{m + 1} + 4\cos^2 \frac{\pi k}{n + 1} \right )^{1/4}.$

Is there any more general result of the number of ways to fully-cover any fully-coverable Polyomino by dominoes

Comment: Off topic but wondering how large is that number? Like exponential?

Comment: @FiniteA, http://oeis.org/A004003 says, "$a(n)$ is the number of different ways to cover a $2n\times2n$ lattice with $2n^2$ dominoes. John and Sachs show that $a(n)=2^nB(n)^2$, where $B(n)\equiv n+1\pmod{32}$ when $n$ is even and $B(n)\equiv(-1)^{(n-1)/2}n\pmod{32}$ when $n$ is odd." The full table is at http://oeis.org/A099390, where you might get some idea of the growth rate, and where there are references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering how many parameters you would need to specify a general polyomino, I can't imagine there being any useful, fully-general result. Here's a special result, quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond: "The Aztec diamond theorem (Noam Elkies, Greg Kuperberg and Michael Larsen et al. 1992) states that the number of domino tilings of the Aztec diamond of order $n$ is $2^{n(n+1)/2}$." Full bibliographic details are given.

I'd suggest typing $$\rm domino\ tiling*$$ into a search engine to see what comes up.

Answer (score 6):

The number of ways to fully-cover a $m$-by-$n$ rectangle with $mn/2$ dominoes was solved by [Kasteleyn](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031891461900635) and as well as [Temperley and Fisher](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786436108243366), both in 1961. This problem is equivalent to counting the number of [perfect matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in the $m$-by-$n$ [grid graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html).

In 1967, Kasteleyn generalized this result to planar graphs. However, instead of a closed form, the number of perfect matchings is computable in [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29). The algorithm is called the [FKT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm) in their honor of all three researchers. He published this algorithm in the chapter titled "Graph theory and crystal physics" of the book [Graph Theory and Theoretical Physics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Graph_Theory_and_Theoretical_Physics.html?id=6QdRAAAAMAAJ).

In 1988, Vijay Vazirani [generalized](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-19487-8_27) the FKT algorithm to graphs which do not contain a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$, the complete bipartite graph with 3 vertices in each partition.